# Remove fade Animation CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cabasicanimation

I tried to change the background color of my `UIImageView` with a `CABasicAnimation`

I did these things with `CABasicAnimation`, but I won't the animation fade, but I don't know if I remove this thing.

This is my code:

```
UIColor *fromColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *toColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue2 & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
CABasicAnimation *colorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
colorAnimation.duration = timeInterval;
colorAnimation.fromValue = (id)fromColor.CGColor;
colorAnimation.toValue = (id)toColor.CGColor;
if (number == 1) {
colorAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
}   if (number == 0) {
    colorAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
}
[self.colorImage.layer addAnimation:colorAnimation forKey:@"backgroundColor"];}
```

Can I remove the fade effect ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Do you want the background colour of the layer to fade or not?

Comment: not fade , i want only change of color

Comment: Why cant you just call `[self.colorImage.Layer setBackgroundColor:myColor.CGColor];`?

Comment: not work with this method

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
[self.colorImage.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: this method remove all my animation , i want remove only the animation fade , i would like have a transition of two color without a animation